# How to use GET method to choose the right table to show ChartJS graph?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, chart.js

I have tables in phpMyAdmin that I want to show charts of using ChartJS. I have a select menu with options that have the same value as the database table name.

I'm making a website that shows test scores in ChartJS charts. I have the user select the subject on one page and then press a button that takes them to a page that shows the chart of the chosen subject.

I have declared the GET variable in PHP on the page that shows the chart

```
$subject_input = $_GET["subject"];
```

I have included the ChartJS script on the same page

```
<script src="ChartJS_SUBJECT_DB.js"></script>
```

Inside the JS file, I have this part that links a PHP page that makes the connection to the database

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: "ChartJS_SUBJECT_DB.php",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var id = [];
    var score = [];
```

Inside the PHP file, I have this part that chooses the table to show the data from

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, score FROM chemistry ORDER BY id");
```

In that example, I get the chemistry data shown just fine. But now it shows the chemistry data no matter what subject the user chooses originally.

I tried simply inserting the variable $subject_input like so

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, score FROM $subject_input ORDER BY id");
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there any way I can use the variable inside there? If not, is there another way to get the data from the right table?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass subject query parameter to Ajax call and try sprintf("SELECT id, score FROM %s ORDER BY id", $subject_input)